# Morse Code to English Translator gives ArrayIndexoutofBounds

Tags: java, exception, morse-code

I have to create morse to English and vice versa translator. The English to morse part works but whenever I try to enter something in morse it gives me an ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception and I am stuck with how to fix it. I have put in a split function, but I am just unsure why I get the exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char[] english = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                            'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                            'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                            's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                            'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4',
                            '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
        String[] morse = { ".-",   "-...", "-.-.", "-..",  ".",
                            "..-.", "--.",  "....", "..",   ".---",
                            "-.-",  ".-..", "--",   "-.",   "---",
                            ".--.", "--.-", ".-.",  "...",  "-",
                            "..-",  "...-", ".--",  "-..-", "-.--",
                            "--..", "|" }
        String userInput;
        int translatorChoice;
        String result; 
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for English to Morse code. Enter 2 for Morse to English:");
        translatorChoice = input.nextInt();
        if (translatorChoice != 1 && translatorChoice !=2 ){
            throw new ArithmeticException("Please enter a valid number");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please input sentence into the translator:");
        userInput = br.readLine();

        if (translatorChoice == 1){
            userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
            englishtoMorse(morse,userInput,english);}
        else if(translatorChoice == 2) {
            morsetoEnglish(english, userInput, morse);}
public static void morsetoEnglish (char[] english, String userInput, String[] morse){
        String[] input = userInput.split("|");
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < morse.length; i++){
                if (morse[j].equals(input[i])) {    
                    System.out.print(english[j]);
                }}}}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it out, but just looking at the code this seems wrong: `for (int j = 0; j < morse.length; i++)` Shouldn't it be `j++`?

Comment: how are you going to tell apart an input like "..." is that an O or just FFF???

Comment: @ka177, I tried making change like for (int j = 0; j < morse.length; j++) and then executed it against .- input and I got output as et                                          
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51566', transport: 'socket'
Enter 1 for English to Morse code. Enter 2 for Morse to English:
2

Please input sentence into the translator:
.-
et

Comment: @karthikakinapelli How do you get an IP address with that code??

Comment: @RubioRic, I have ran the code from intellij , So IP address you are seeing in my comment is from Intellij Console :)

Comment: Your `morse` array is shorter than your `english` array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working code. 3 changes were to be made, first of all, split over `"|"` had to be changed to correct regex `"\\|"` to literally split on `'|'`. `split()` takes regular expression as an argument and `'|'` is a special character in regex, so you need to escape it with regexe's `\`, but then, when translating regex to java string you escape it again. The result is `\\|` 
Second, inner `for` loop can stop when strings matched, thus break added.
Third, variable `i` changed to `j` in inner `for` loop incrementation.

```
    public static void morsetoEnglish (char[] english, String userInput, String[] morse){
        String[] input = userInput.split("\\|");
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < morse.length; j++){
                if (morse[j].equals(input[i])) {    
                    System.out.print(english[j]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Here's some test input/output:

```
Enter 1 for English to Morse code. Enter 2 for Morse to English:
2
Please input sentence into the translator:
.--.|.|-|
pet
```

Answer (score 0):

so, I think this could do with a bit of a logic re-work

```
public static void englishToMorse(char[] english, String userInput, String[] morse){
    char[] chars = userInput.toCharArray();

    String englishCharsAsString = new String(english);
    for (char character: chars) {
        if (character == ' ') {
            System.out.println(" ");
            continue;
        }

        int index = englishCharsAsString.indexOf(character);
        System.out.println(morse[index]);
    }
}
```

let me explain what's happening here, we should also be able to reverse engineer this to make the `morseToEnglish` method.

1. So we start by taking the users input and converting it into a char array, this way we know what the users individual characters are.
2. Next we convert the English array of chars into one string, this way we can find the index of a letter in that string and use that to map it against the morse code array
3. Now we loop through all the chars in the users input, find the index of that char in the English string, then use that index to grab the morse code representation.